# How to print text with style in Text Area? (wordpress)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, textarea

i want to print text with style in text area, so I use code:

```
<textarea name="creteria_1_text" id="creteria_1_text" rows="5" cols="100" class="custom"><?php echo $creteria_1_text; ?></textarea>
```

But all text goes in one line. Ex: *Abc *cba *bca

How to print text with format? a few sentence in new line,
Ex:

```
*Abc
*cba 
*bca
```

Or with in new line and space between Ex:

*Abc

*cba

*bca

Should I style some how or what should I do?

Comment: Are you using any text editor or plain textarea?

Comment: It is plain textarea.

Comment: The provided answer should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace Php print code with this

```
<?php $newStr = str_replace(' ',"\n",$creteria_1_text);
      echo $newstr;
?>
```